# RTK Query - how to access headers?

Tags: redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I have a working RTK Query api, reading from a backend that after a successful login was sending the token in the payload.

The backend API changed and now the token comes in the response's `Authorization` header and I can't figure out how to read it.

This is what I had before, on my reducer. I used a matcher for when the request was fulfilled and stored the token in the payload:

```js
// reducer.js
const authReducer = createSlice({
  // ...
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addMatcher(backendApi.endpoints.login.matchFulfilled, (state, { payload }) => {
      // save the payload.token in localstorage
    }
  }
});
```

It seems like getting the headers is not straightforward, and I actually can't find the `Authorization` header when trying to get the headers from the request:

```js
// reducer.js
const authReducer = createSlice({
  // ...
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addMatcher(backendApi.endpoints.login.matchFulfilled, (state, { meta }) => {
      const headers = meta.baseQueryMeta.response.headers; // this is a Headers {} object
      console.log(headers.get('content-type')); // prints application/json; charset=utf-8
      console.log(headers.get('authorization')); // prints undefined
    }
  }
});
```

When I try to debug and print all headers with `console.log(Array.from(headers))` this is what I get:

```
[
  [
    "cache-control",
    "max-age=0, private, must-revalidate"
  ],
  [
    "content-type",
    "application/json; charset=utf-8"
  ]
]
```

It's super strange because the response has many more headers, but I can't access them.

Any guidance here? Maybe it's not possible to read the headers this way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing everything right there. If `headers.get('authorization')` comes back as `undefined` I would assume it is a CORS issue preventing your JavaScript from accessing that.

So your server would need to set the correct CORS headers, nothing to do on the client side.